# variable not getting updated in doInBackground method of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use the following code to obtain the `result` value, but the it never seems to update. I am checking the result in the class called `startPosting()`:

```
public class PostDataThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  String [] data;
  Context context;
  int result = 0;

  public int startPosting(int type,String data[], Context c) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = c;
    this.execute();
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Connect c = new Connect();
    c.start(Constant.RECEIVED_MESSAGE, data, context);
    result = 444;
    return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    //          
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `result`? Please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: @ MisterSquonk result(int) is variable . I am initializing it to an arbitrary value while declaring. After executing doInBackground method(called from the same class by this.execute()), there is no change in the result

Comment: we either don't know what `Connect` is. Is there a possibility that `c.start(...)` returns the same result than it has before? please provide more source code, so we can help you and get an idea whats going on.

Comment: @Rafael T connect do some stuff in the background. yeas there is a possibility of returning the same result. but, i tried modifying it to " result = newValue;". But, again same old value.
and i am also not able to trace "result" in debug mode!!

Comment: When are you checking the value of `result`? After `onPostExecute` or are you expecting `result` to be set immediate after you call the `AsyncTask`? Don't forget that AsyncTask is **asynchronous**.

Comment: @Marvin : I have update the Question with full code.

Comment: As Marvin indicates - `doInBackground(..)` is asynchronous. So you create an instance of your `PostDataThread` class and then call `startPosting(...)`??? If this is the case then a call to `this.execute()` will start `doInBackground(...)` but will immediately return. At this point the next line is `return result;` which will more than likely still be `0`. This really isn't a good way to design an `AsyncTask` sub-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `result` is not getting updated is because you're attempting to check it *immediately* after you call the `AsyncTask`.

Here's how you could re-structure it:

```
public class PostDataThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

  String [] data;
  Context context;
  int res = 0;

  public PostDataThread(int type, String data[], Context c) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = c;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Connect c = new Connect();
    c.start(Constant.RECEIVED_MESSAGE, data, context);
    res = 444;
    return res;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Result is: " +result);
  }

}
```

And to call it:

```
PostDataThread p = new PostDataThread(type, data, context);
p.execute();
```

Then modify `onPostExecute`to do whatever you need to with `result`.

Comment: @sushantkr Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 2):

if result is an int try this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private int result = 0

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{
         public Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg){
             //Conncet c = new Connect();
             //result=c.start(Constant.RECEIVED_MESSAGE, data, context);
             //commented out for debug purposes
             return 23774
         }

         public void onPostExcecute(Integer res){
             result = res
         }
    }

    public void onResume(){
         super.onResume();
         MyTask mt = new MyTask();
         mt.execute(0);
         Handler h = new Handler(new Handler.Callback(){
              public void handleMessage(Message m){
                  //check result here
                  Log.i("RESULT", result);
              }
         });
         //takes 5 seks to wait
         h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 5000);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanku......i got it now. I can't give a vote up :-| (my reputation is 8!) thanks a lot :-)